# Is this setText bug?

Tags: java, android

## Problem

My TextView is set to the new string but it will set to previous String after that.

## Layout

```xml
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qr_code_instruction"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=" "
        android:textColor="@color/qr_code_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom" />
```

## Switch Listener

```java
glareSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){
                    qr_code_instruction.setText("----------");
                    camera2Manager.setGlareSwitch(true); //turn off glare
                }
                else{
                    camera2Manager.setGlareSwitch(false); //turn on glare
                }
            }
        });
```

Checking Class Part

```java
        if(!glareSwitch){
            System.out.println("1");
            glare = helper.glareDetection(bitmap);
            if(glare){
                ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.qr_code_instruction)).setText(" ");
            } else {
                ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.qr_code_instruction)).setText("Glare Detected");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("2");
            glare = true;
        }
```

## Bug

1. When switch is unchecked it will keep print "1" and check for glare

It will update textview either " " / "Glare Detected" based on the return result.

2. When switch is checked it will keep print 2 and do nothing.

It will update textview to "----------" then it's set to previous latest text either " " / "Glare Detected".

## Output of switch click

[image]

## ctrl + shift + f

[image]

## Update

```java
        if(!glareSwitch){
            System.out.println("1");
            glare = helper.glareDetection(bitmap);
//            if(glare){
//                ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.qr_code_instruction)).setText(" ");
//            } else {
//                ((TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.qr_code_instruction)).setText("Glare Detected");
//            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("2");
            glare = true;
        }
```

By commenting out the setText in the class. It will not replace "----------" when switch is checked.

Comment: What have you given for textview in layout file?

Comment: Hi, I update my question with layout for textView already.